# Converter Html (SVG) para PDF usando DomPDF

Tags: php, html5, svg, dompdf

Com o código a baixo estou conseguindo gerar o PDF normalmente. 
Só a "figura" que estou gerando utilizando o **SVG** não está sendo mostrada.

O que tenho que mudar para que a figura seja incluída no PDF?

*** Lembrando que não posso alterar nada no HTML.

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    require "vendor/autoload.php";

    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    use Dompdf\Options;

    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);
    $options->set('debugKeepTemp', TRUE);
    $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF($options);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("exemplo.html");
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $html = $doc->saveHTML();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("exemplo.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));

?>
```

**exemplo.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg width="400" height="110">
            <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não é uma respota relacionada, mas  pode ser uma solução gerar uma  imagem do  html usando ocanvas2html.js e depois converte em  imagem no serivodor com o base64 e salvar no  pdf

Comment: Vou fazer testes.... Obrigado